# Douglas-Peuker and equal distances

Tags: 2d-graphics

I have a polyline and I want to simplify it with Douglas-Peucker. It's an easy algorithm, but what if there are points with the same distance. What point should I select? Is there a reasonable solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider the curvature in that case too. If the curvature is small - then it is a flat region - so you can safely remove it - your 4th point for example. If the curvature is large (your 5th point for example), even if the distance is the same, you should most likely leave it alone.

I would actually recommend a curvature based method coming before Douglas-Peucker.

Comment: Could you please suggest a good "curvature based method"?

Comment: You can start by removing points with the smallest curvature (as an approximation, you can use the angle that they form).